# Static variable in PHP

Tags: php

If I run the following PHP code, I get 123. I don't understand the logic behind it. What I think is when I call the function each time it suppose to output 1. So the output should be like 111.

```
function keep_track() {
  STATIC $count = 0;
  $count++;
  print $count;
}

keep_track();
keep_track();
keep_track();

// output 123
```

I know that a static variable holds the value even after the function exits but in the above function I am assigning a value in the very first line, yet it still adding +1 with the previous value of `$count`.

Could you please explain this? (I am sorry if I sound like a stupid.. but I am trying to find out how exactly this happening)

Comment: You're assigning the **initial** value only.

Comment: The [PHP manual on static variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) explains this well

Comment: Because, `$count` inside the function is incrementing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$count` is initialized only in first call of function and every time the method is called, it increments `$count`.

In this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), scroll down to `Using static variables` for a better understanding.

Comment: Is that because I have `Static` before `$count` ?

Comment: Yes. `STATIC` is a keyword that is used to mark variables as static, and this behavious is due to that keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) So the function is just overlooking my `STATIC $count = 0;` when I am calling it for the second time and going directly to `$count++;` and this is all happening due to `static` Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. that is absolutely correct. Think of STATIC as a singleton - Once initialized, it would not reinitialize

Answer (score 3):

The code `static $count = 0;` is executed once upon compilation which is why with each call of your function the value is not overwritten. See the note "Static declarations are resolved in compile-time." at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This'd still output `123`. The questioner expected `111` and asks for an explanation.

Comment: @Omar I am not actually looking for a code to get 111 :) I am trying to find out why/how my code is generating 123 :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: Updated my answer to include an explanation for it